# Ajax success into a table with progressbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following problem in my javascript code.
I try to put my ajax response into a table.
All works fine.
But now i'v tried to show s porgressbar in one of the columns for each entry.
Dosen't work.

Here is the main piece of code which do the work:

```
[...]

,success:function(data) {
$("#table").empty();
$.each(data,function(index,Data) {

var process_result = Data.accuracyI;
var id = Data.UIDI;


if (Data.entire == 0) {
    $("#entire").text("No succeed").css({
        "color": "red",
        "font-weight": "bold"
    });
} else {

    $("#entire").html(Data.EntireI).css({
        "color": "green",
        "font-weight": "bold"
    });
    $tr = $("<tr/>");
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.lastNameI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.firstNameI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.aliasI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.pepI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.dobI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.place_of_birthI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").text(Data.countriesI));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").html("<div id='" + id + "'></div>"));
    $tr.append($("<td/>").html(Data.PDFI));
    $("#result").append($tr);

    $(id).progressbar({
        value: process_result
    });
}


});

[...]
```

So here you can see the code.
My problem is that the progressbar in the column after 'Countries' is not showing for each entry - just for the first in the table.
Bizarrely if i change the 'div' Element to, for example the varibale process_result, each entry of the table shows his own number correctly.

So what is the misstake i have to change?

Thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are still in the same each loop you can do this, more in line with your code:

```
var $div = $("<div></div>").attr("id", id);
$tr.append($("<td/>").append($div)); 
$tr.append($("<td/>").html(Data.PDFI));
$("#result").append($tr);

$div.progressbar({
    value: process_result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = Data.UIDI;

[...]

$(id).progressbar({
    value: process_result
});
```

the variable `id` should represent a selector. see [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

### solution

```
$('#' + id).progressbar({
    value: process_result
});
```